# Fit css grid cell with image

Tags: html, css

I'm using a css grid for a landing page layout.

And I'm having an issue with the hero section of the page.

The image that is in one of the columns, does not resize as I would like it to do.[image: see attached screenshot] I would like the picture to fit the whole cell and resize inside the cell proportionally while not getting higher than the content left of it (mockup laptop and blue column).

This is the code:

```
<div class="container">

      <section id="hero-section">
        <img class="hero-logo" src="img" alt="">
        <h1 class="hero-h1">bla bla</h1>
      </section>

      <section id="bg-section">
          <img class="bg-img" src="img" alt="Engineer wearing helmet">
      </section>

etc...
</div>
```

So the container is set to grid and the picture

```
#bg-section {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 6;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg-img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I've tried to do flex on #bg-section or height: 100% on the image, the image is filling the whole cell but the image won't keep the aspect ratio in this way.

Please help

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle or add code to reproduce this issue

Comment: look at object-fit to keep the ratio, but it will be cropped to do so  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit , you can also take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position to manage which sides / area are to be cropped

Comment: Try adding `object-fit: cover;` to `.bg-img` class

Comment: This partially solved it. In order to make object-fit work I've also had to set height to 100% not only width. But everything great now, thank you!

Comment: try using a `background-image`.